# Как вывести массив в массиве красиво разложив?

Tags: php

Простите за банальный возможно вопрос, но гуглить уже нет сил конкретно свой пример. Как красиво (возможно с помощью `foreach`) разложить такой массив, вывел через `print_r`:

```
Array

(
[0] => Array
    (
        [price-name] => Терапия
        [price-repeater] => Array
            (

                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Приём терапевта (осмотр, постановка первичного диагноза)
                        [price] => 500
                        [sale] => 450
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Консультация по результатам исследований
                        [price] => 400
                        [sale] => 390
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Консультация по зооветеринарным вопросам (15 минут)
                        [price] => 800
                        [sale] => 785
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [price-name] => Диагностика
        [price-repeater] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Пример услуги
                        [price] => 1150
                        [sale] => 1150
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Чтобы вывело нечто вида:

```html
<div id="1">
<h2>Терапия</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Наименование услуги</th>
      <th scope="col">Стоимость</th>
      <th scope="col">Стоимость со скидкой</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Приём терапевта (осмотр, постановка первичного диагноза)</th>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Консультация по результатам исследований</th>
      <td>400</td>
      <td>390</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Консультация по зооветеринарным вопросам (15 минут)</th>
      <td>800</td>
      <td>785</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="2">
<h2>Диагностика</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Наименование услуги</th>
      <th scope="col">Стоимость</th>
      <th scope="col">Стоимость со скидкой</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Пример услуги</th>
      <td>1150</td>
      <td>1150</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Так в чем вопрос то?

Comment: Я так понимаю рекурсия в поиске не подошла или что то не так с циклами у человека)

Comment: Вы читали [документацию по `foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) ? что именно вызывает у Вас проблему?

Comment: проблема в слабых знаниях, обычный цикл я еще напишу, а вот рекурсию боюсь не осилю, вот и проблема)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($ar as $key=>$item)
    {
        echo '<div id="'.($key+1).'">
        <h2>'.$item['price-name'].'</h2>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Наименование услуги</th>
              <th scope="col">Стоимость</th>
              <th scope="col">Стоимость со скидкой</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>';
        foreach($item['price-repeater'] as $item2)
        {
            echo '
            <tr>
                <th>'.$item2['name'].'</th>
                <td>'.$item2['price'].'</td>
                <td>'.$item2['sale'].'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
            echo '
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        '; 
    }
```

[Тест](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d66035e61d6e096efcc87a24a836cc568d5c84a)

Comment: Это верный ответ. Так же можно использовать альтернативный синтаксис перебора массива на примере: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array